# What way is best to interpret $\Re(\int f dz)= \int Pdx+Qdy$

Tags: complex-analysis

What way is best to interpret/"think about";

$\Re(\int f dz) = \int Pdx+Qdy$

I.e  the real part of a complex valued function $f$ along a curve in $\mathbb{C}$ and the equality with its "corresponding" line integral in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$.

I dont know weather just to write $f=P-iQ$(corrected after answer) and consider the complex measure $d(x+iy)$ or start messing around with vectors and scalar product. Im not even sure the first way is vaild, it seams to easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write it this way, it is actually $f=P-iQ$ and $dz=dx+ i dy$. Then
$$ \int f dz = \int (P dx + Q dy) + i\int ( P dy - Q dx) $$
You should  interpret the integral as a path integral, e.g. if $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$ for some piecewise $C^1$ functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ for say $t\in [a,b]$. Then
$$ \int f dz = \int_a^b (P(x,y) \frac{dx}{dt} + Q(x,y) \frac{dy}{dt}) dt + i\int_a^b ( P(x,y) \frac{dy}{dt} - Q(x,y) \frac{dx}{dt}) dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $f$ in terms of its real and imaginary parts as $f=u+iv$ and realize that $dz=dx+idy$ (where $z=x+iy$). Then
$$
\int f(z)dz=\int  (u+iv)(dx+idy)=\int (udx-vdy)+i\int(udy+vdx).
$$